# Regex to group data

Tags: regex

I am looking to extract data using Regex - Example::

http://www.test.com/?name=A_B_C_D_E_F&gclid=something

or

http://www.test.com/?name=A_B_C_D_E_F

I would like to extract the next 4 words following `name=A_`

So the desired output is -

```
B
C
D
E
```

I am looking to extract these values using backreferences i.e.

`$1` will return `B` `$2` will return `C`
`$3` will return `D` and `$4` will return `E`

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: With regexes, it helps to explain which language you are using the regexes from.  The answers for C, C++, C#, Perl, Python, PHP, Java, Ruby have much in common and much that's different in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?:\?|&)name=A(_[^_&]+)(_[^_&]+)(_[^_&]+)(_[^_&]+)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question to show that the ampersand& is not always mandatory.

Comment: @thinking_hydrogen - I think you may have misunderstood. In the beginning, I'm saying there can be a question mark _or_ an ampersand. In the rest, I'm looking for strings of non-`_` and non-`&` separated by underscores. For example, I didn't know if `%20` (a common occurrence in URLs) was acceptable within your "word". In other words, the ampserands in my expression have nothing to do with whether there is an ampersand following. I'm just saying the regex should "quit" if an ampersand is encountered, _e.g. before four words are found_.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the expected result:

`(?<=name=A_)([^\_]+)_([^\_]+)_([^\_]+)_([^\_]+)`

http://regex101.com/r/xO1oE8

Comment: Thanks, I got sequence not recognised error ?<=... but slight modification fixed it - (?=.*?name=A_([^\_]+)_([^\_]+)_([^\_]+)_([^\_]+)).*

Comment: Which language are you using to process the string?
The '<' may have to be escaped with an escape character.

Comment: Or there's a chance that the regex language does not support positive look-behind.